# Azure AD B2C logout does not redirect on IOS Expo react native

Tags: react-native, expo, azure-ad-b2c

I am using `openBrowserAsync` to call the logout endpoint :

```js
export const Logout = async () => {
    const uri = `${discovery.endSessionEndpoint}?post_logout_redirect_uri=myapp://auth/`
    await openBrowserAsync(uri)
}
```

This works on Android : the browser open the page and redirects to the app when finished then following login request ask the user to input email/password.

But not on IOS, the browser opens a blank page and stays there. When closing the page by pressing "OK" the following login requests automatically logs the user without asking credentials.

It looks like the browser does not clear the user's session from the browser

I have put the redirect URI in the azure app registration. [doc used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-native-application?tabs=app-reg-ga)

I am using Custom policies.

Answer (score 0):

using `openAuthSessionAsync` from `expo-web-browser` fixed the issue

```js
export const Logout = async () => {
    const uri = `${discovery.endSessionEndpoint}?post_logout_redirect_uri=myapp://auth/`
    return await openAuthSessionAsync(uri, "myapp://auth/");
}
```